# Getting classes of a function's parameter list in R

Tags: r, parameters, function-definition

Is it possible to get the class for each parameter in a function?

For example, here is the function definition of `sd`

```
> sd
function (x, na.rm = FALSE) 
sqrt(var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), 
na.rm = na.rm))
<bytecode: 0x7ff6b11067c8>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

I am trying to get a list of possible classes for `x` within the function.

Here, if I'm reading the definition correctly, `x` may be a vector, factor, or double. `na.rm` is of class boolean.

Is there an automated way to figure this out?

Comment: It may be easier to print the help file to the console and extract the arguments from it.

Comment: I had tried that. The help file lists `sd(x, na.rm = FALSE)` in the Usage section and describes the arguments, but there doesn't appear a way of inferring the class other than reading what's in the description. I was hoping there was a method or function to help me do this automatically.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is to do something with `all.names(body(sd))`

Comment: It is not possible to do this automatically, because what the classes of the arguments are is not defined anywhere. You can use anything as `x`, but it may happen that the function crashes at some point.